# A cryptocurrency with an irrevocable "doomsday"

Tags: encryption, hash

EDIT: I've moved this question over to a more approprite StackExchange: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19150/ways-to-make-a-doomsday-cryptocurrency-which-becomes-untradable
Feel free to delete.

As a social experiment (**not a money-making scheme**), I'm interested in developing a crazy cryptocurrency which, by its very design, will become worthless and untradable after a certain point. Ideally, this would be a fixed date like "January 1st 2020," but it could also be after a predictable event occurs, such as after one million trades have been made, or once a super expensive computation completes. I, the designer of the currency, should not have any ability to prevent this "doomsday," postpone it, or even cause it to happen early. Lastly, my users should not have the ability to defy the doomsday by creating their own fork of the code.

The current idea I'm running with is to have there be a "super-key," which works as a universal private key and allows you to break into anyone's account. Since the accounts would cease to be secure, the currency would be worthless. I would generate this key, then encrypt it in such a way that it would take years (but not decades!) to crack, then release it publicly. There's a few downsides to this approach, mainly that I would not be able to guarantee that I myself don't own the super-key.

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to implement this.

Comment: Estimates of how long it'll take to crack a key are just that, estimates.  The actual time to crack a key depends on how much computing power you have at your disposal.  Since you don't know how much computing power other parties (such as large wealthy corporations and government intelligence agencies) have, you can never be sure that your "super-key" hasn't been cracked before your intended deadline.

Comment: That's true, but you can make an estimation. The absolute shortest amount of time it would take is if a botnet the size of storm were to focus on the task. The longest amount of time would be if I kept the crack running in the background on my own computer.

Comment: That's not the "absolute shortest amount of time".  Specially-designed cracking hardware can be much more efficient than the average PC owned by someone who doesn't have enough sense to stay away from malware.  Specially-designed hardware is expensive, but if your hypothetical cryptocurrency has economic value and the "super-key" is known to exist, you can expect that people will expend a lot of resources to crack it.  (Look at the specialized hardware people have built for Bitcoin mining, for example.)

Comment: Besides, even with a known amount of computing power, the exact time when the key is found comes down to probability.  Brute force will find the key after searching half the keyspace *on average*, but it could get lucky and guess the right key on the first try, or unlucky and have to search the whole keyspace.  So your "super-key" *could* be cracked immediately (though that's extremely unlikely), or could last twice as long as you'd intended.

Comment: Perhaps if it were possible to monitor the progress of people attempting to break the superkey?

Comment: Good luck with asking the NSA and KGB for a report on how their cryptographic efforts are coming along.  :-P

Answer (score 0):

I'll include one other solution that I've found:
ftp://ftp.deas.harvard.edu/techreports/tr-22-06.pdf
This would rely upon a 3rd party service to gradually crack a file that would somehow break the currency (such as the aforementioned super-key).